# Is there any way to save Mui DataGrid Toolbar's state?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, toolbar

I'm using React [Mui](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/) DataGrid component with default Toolbar. Users are allow to configure the grid in multiple ways using toolbar such as sort order/hide columns/filter/change density and etc. Is there any simple way to export(save)/import(pass) toolbar settings?

Answer (score 2):

You can export the whole table state to json and save it to localstorage and retreive it when rendering the component.

We store the state every time the user edit the columns width or edit the column visibility. You could add also the save method when the user change filters.

```
const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

useEffect(() => {
  try {
    const stateJSON = localStorage.getItem("ORDERS_TABLE_STATE");
    if (stateJSON) apiRef.current.restoreState(JSON.parse(stateJSON));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}, []);

return (
  <DataGridPro
    apiRef={apiRef}
    onColumnVisibilityModelChange={() => {
      const state = apiRef.current.exportState();
      localStorage.setItem("ORDERS_TABLE_STATE", JSON.stringify(state));
    }}
    onColumnWidthChange={() => {
      const state = apiRef.current.exportState();
      localStorage.setItem("ORDERS_TABLE_STATE", JSON.stringify(state));
    }}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use columnVisibilityModel and filterModel:

```
const visibilityJSON = localStorage.getItem("bonds_visibility")
const visibilityModel = (visibilityJSON) ? JSON.parse(visibilityJSON) : {}
const [columnVisibilityModel, setColumnVisibilityModel] = useState<GridColumnVisibilityModel>(visibilityModel)
const filterJSON = localStorage.getItem("bonds_filter")
const initialFilterModel = (filterJSON) ? JSON.parse(filterJSON) : {items: []}
const [filterModel, setFilterModel] = useState<GridFilterModel>(initialFilterModel)
...
return (
    <DataGrid
        ...
        columnVisibilityModel={columnVisibilityModel}
        onColumnVisibilityModelChange={(newModel) => {
            localStorage.setItem("bonds_visibility", JSON.stringify(newModel))
            setColumnVisibilityModel(newModel)
        }}
        filterModel={filterModel}
        onFilterModelChange={(newModel) => {
            localStorage.setItem("bonds_filter", JSON.stringify(newModel))
            setFilterModel(newModel)
        }}
    />
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this precious answer