# Is there any way to save MUI X Premium DataGrid Toolbar's state?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I'm using MUX premium and I can't store toolbar's state in localstorage to persist my column's order, I've tried [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74046329/is-there-any-way-to-save-mui-datagrid-toolbars-state) but not worked for me..
This is my demo code :

```js
const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

const columns={[{field: ‘second’ }, { field: ‘first’ }]}

useEffect(() => {
  try {
    const stateJSON = localStorage.getItem("state");
    if (stateJSON) apiRef.current.restoreState(JSON.parse(stateJSON));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}, []);

return (
  <DataGridPremium
  columns={columns}
    apiRef={apiRef}
    onColumnVisibilityModelChange={() => {
      const state = apiRef.current.exportState();
      localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(state));
    }}
    onColumnWidthChange={() => {
      const state = apiRef.current.exportState();
      localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(state));
    }}
  />
);
```

But when I change my comuns order and press F5 the order is reset to default one, not persisted one.

Have you any ideas how to achieve this please ? any demo link are welcome

Answer (score 0):

`onStateChange` lets you track the state and `initialState` to set the initial datagrid state

```
const columns=[{field: 'second' }, { field: 'first' }]

const initialState = useMemo(() => {
     const stateJSON = localStorage.getItem("state");
     if (!stateJSON) {
        return {}
     }
     try {
        return JSON.parse(stateJSON);
     } catch {
        return {}
     }
}, [])


return (
  <DataGridPremium
     onStateChange={(state) => {
       localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(state));
     }}
     initialState={initialState}
     columns={columns}
     rows={[]}
  />
);
```

Comment: thank you, it's store the state in localstorage but when I reload the page it not take my initialState

Comment: @Tania12 can you give more details. Are you sure that initialState has value?

Comment: Yes, the initialState is different than the state in localstorage, it take default value.